# “Any question?” in French?

Tags: questions, oral

In my French class, I heard my professor say something like “De question ?” to ask if we any question.

Did I hear this right? If so, what is the grammatical structure of “de”? I'd thought it should be “de la question” with the partitive article.

If not, what is a natural way to ask “Any question ?” in French?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was actually :

> ***Des*** questions ?

a shortened version of :

> *Est-ce qu'il y a des questions ?*

or

> *Est-ce que vous avez des questions ?*

Note that *questions* are always countable in French so there is no way to use a partitive here. ***<s>De la</s> question*** is impossible.

Comment: Could you help me clarify what "disjunctive" mean, at least in this context? Thank you.

Comment: Clarified with a better adjective.